# How to get the actual value after subtracting discount(%)

Tags: percentage, discount

I want to get the total amount with the help of Final amount and Discount rate.

For Example.

Grand total  = 100

Discount     = 15%

Final Amount =100*.15=85

if I have only two variables

Final amount = 85

Discount     = 15%

Grand total  = ?

Now I can get back Grand total with the help of "Final Amount" and "Discount rate"?

Comment: Have a look to my solution

Comment: To make it more simple, the formula is `Grand total = Final amount / ( 1 - Discount )` so in this particular case: `Grand total = 85 / ( 1 - 0.15 ) = 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Grand Total = X

X-(X * 15 %) = 85
 then if you find the value of X then your Grand total can e found.

X - 3X/20 = 85

17X= 85*20

X = (85/17)*20

X =100

Put it .. You will find the Grand Total

Answer (score 1):

Let x = Grand Total.

We know that

`100-100*0.15=85`

Let's substitute 100 with X.

`x-(x*0.15) = 85`

then we can simply apply basic PEMDAS operation. So let's multiply

`x-0.15x = 85`

we know that the first x is = 1, so

`1x-0.15x = 85`

which equals to

`0.85x=85`

divide 0.85 on both sides to find X

`0.85x/0.85 = 85/0.85 = 100`